# How to customize color for TOC, LOF and LOT in {article} class while using {tocloft}?

Tags: table-of-contents, color

I have a document using `article` class (please not ask me why don't use report class). The article has TOC, LOF, LOT and Nomenclature.

The MWE:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside] {article}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{subfigure}
 \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
 \usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
 \makenomenclature

 \usepackage{kpfonts} %[uprightRoman, uprightgreeks]
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

 \usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
   \setlength\cftbeforefigskip{1 ex} % list of figures
   \setlength\cftbeforetabskip{1 ex} % list of tables
   \setlength\cftbeforesecskip{1 em} % spacing before sec title
   \setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{1.8 em} 
   \setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{4 cm} 
   \setlength{\nomitemsep}{0.5 ex} 

 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \titleformat{\subsection} {\large \bfseries \color{RoyalBlue}} {\thesubsection}{1 ex}{}
 \titleformat{\subsubsection}  {\normalsize  \bfseries  \color{RoyalBlue}}       {\thesubsubsection}{1 ex}{}  %\slshape
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}   % table of content depth
\definecolor{RoyalBlue}{RGB}{0, 35, 102}

 \begin{document}
  Hello, world!
  \tableofcontents
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables
  \printnomenclature[2 cm]       
  \section{Introduction}
  \section{DEM}
  \subsection{Math model}
  \subsubsection{Particle collision}
  \nomenclature{DEM}{Distinct Element Method}
\end{document}
```

The color of section headings and `Nomenclature` is changed as expected. However the color of `Contents` and `List of Figures` etc. remains `black`.

Having looked through `article.cls`, I tried

```
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\section*{\contentsname
     \@mkboth{%
       \MakeUppercase \textcolor{RoyalBlue} {\contentsname} }{\MakeUppercase \textcolor{RoyalBlue}\contentsname}}%
\@starttoc{toc}%
}
```

However, it turned out not working. By the way, I used `tocloft` to define the LOF, LOT entries spacing, don't know whether it has some side-effect.

So how to figure this out?

**Edit 1:**  Found out the problem lies with: `\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}` . But I need these packages! Or should I redefine  the spacing without the `tocloft` package?

Comment: Your MWE does not compile for me, I get `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \undefinedpagestyle`. Instead of `subfigure`, try the `subfig` package, it is usually seen as superior. Most important however, load `tocloft` *after* subfigure.

Comment: MWE was edited, now should work. Loading `subfigure` before `tocloft` does not work. I suspect `tocloft` redefines the default commands `\contentsname` and `\tableofcontents`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\color{RoyalBlue}}
```

to change the color of the ToC to blue. Add other stuff like `\Large\bfseries` to it, to get bold large title text. Similarly, change `\cftloftitlefont` for the List of Figures.

Comment: Thanks, i just searched for the keywords `color/colour` in the `tocloft` RADEME, no words found. So I thought no option to change font color,  LOL